# How to get Latest Version code of Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I want to implement Picasso in my project but when i try to implement **Picasso** in my project. I visited their website to get dependency. But they removed the latest version number so i can't find what is latest version number of **Picasso**.

If someone comment down the version i'll be glad

Website Link([Click Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/#download))

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest version is 2.71828

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Available on their github https://github.com/square/picasso

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should have visited their [Github](https://github.com/square/picasso). It's mentioned there.

The latest version is 2.71828.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

[image]

Comment: in past most of time i picked dependency from their website. So i didn't checked their github

Answer (score 2):

Just visit https://square.github.io/picasso/#download

copy GRADLE link: implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'

To get the version from https://github.com/square/picasso/releases

Version 2.8 is the latest as of today's post Oct 04 2020 which was released this on Aug 10 2020.

Comment: That's right Sir and welcome to Stack overflow but today is Oct 04 not Aug 04